# iOS Data persistence when backgrounding app

Tags: ios, properties, persistence

In my iOS application I have a custom class with a property with a strong attribute.  When I hit the home button to background the app and resume again it appears the property value stays in memory.  However if I kill the application the property value is reset (it doesn't stay in memory).  Is it safe to assume the property will stay in memory as long as my application stays in memory?

Comment: Yes, but you don't have any guarantee that it will stay in memory -- the system could cause your app to exit if other apps need the memory.

Comment: If my application goes out of memory will it disappear from the task manager (double click home button)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If your app receives the didRecieveMemoryWarning, you have a chance to clean some memory. The OS will attempt to do this on some views if outlets are not currently in use. If this does not free enough memory, the OS will probably send the message a few more times, and will eventually kill the app.

There is no automatic way for the OS to clear a single property without killing the whole app. It is safe to assume that your memory exists while the app hasn't been killed.